# ES6 module import a function value

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I see a lot of node librairies using this syntax:

```
var lib = require('lib')();
```

I was wondering what was the ES6 equivalent  ?

For now, I use the following syntax:

```
import libfunc from 'lib';
var lib = libfunc();
```

Is there a more elegant way to perform this import ?

Comment: Nope, you cannot make it shorter.

Comment: Although I try to use the ES6 syntax where I can, I still stay with require like this: "const React = require('react');". But as far as I know, "import" is the ES6 equivalent of require.

Comment: @Apfelbox `require` is a nodejs-specific function. `import` is a part of the standard.

Comment: Too bad, thanks for the answer @zerkms !

Comment: @zerkms yes, you're 100% right. I was just thinking that It is possible to use import instead (even in node libraries) - my bad sorry